# Redirect not working from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

The console log statement is working so I know the function is working except for that there are no errors or any other messages. It is just not redirecting. This is the code:

```
    const RedirectNow = () => {
      if (registered) {
        console.log("RedirectNow")
        return <Redirect to='/home' />;
      }
    }
```

The `'/home'` path is specified in the router in index.js, is that the right way? I also tried a relative path with another file in the same folder to make sure but it did not work.
Does someone know what's going wrong? Maybe there's a better  way to do this?

Comment: I would do this with a useEffect and useHistory
```
const history = useHistory();
useEffect(() => { if (!registered) history.replace('/home') }, [history, registered])
```

Comment: @dbuchet I am new to react so unfamiliar with history and useeffect. Could you clarify something, will I need to visit /home before this so that it is cached in history or something? If so, then what if I want to redirect to another page that I haven't visited yet as I want to redirect to profile after logging in for first time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useHistory hook for this purpose

```
import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then later:

```
const history=useHistory()
```

and as a replacement of redirect statement you can write:

```
history.push('/home')
```

Comment: I am new to react so unfamiliar with history. Could you clarify something, will I need to visit /home before this so that it is caches in history or something? If so, than what if I want to redirect to another page that I haven't visited yet as I want to redirect to profile after logging in for first time. Thank you.